# Integrating Python code in Excel such that one can automate the task using excel?

Tags: python, excel, integration

I am trying to develop a Python program for a task. The task is to find all routes in a state/county which are not reachable within 60 minutes from certain locations.
The task will take data (route info, speed limit, etc.) from excel.  The excel data will be changed because there are many states/counties in USA/Canada.

***I want to link the python code with excel such that we can get answers by clicking on the excel sheet.***

Can you tell me how this can be done? Any ideas?

Comment: You'd like to input data in Excel, have Python update it, and see the updated results in Excel immediately? So Excel is kinda the UI for your Python program?

Comment: If you want to load data from a spreadsheet and save data to a spreadsheet, that's a much more well-trodden path, but SO is not a place for library (package) recommendations.

Comment: Yes, I want to do that "input data in Excel, have Python update it, and see the updated results in Excel immediately". Because the excel file will be submitted to a non-technical person so that they can easily understand the result.